# Load many pictures in a form

Tags: delphi

I was asked to develop a game called "Flag Quiz" in which the player have to guess the correct name of the flag that appears in the middle of the screen.

[image]

Of course I have a lot of pictures (221 flags) and I have to put them inside the program because, when the button `Play` is pressed, the program has to pick randomly 10 of these flags.

**Problem**
I was thinking to use an `ImageList` but the flags are 480x311 and so Delphi asks me to separate the picutre in 30 different bitmaps. Can I do anything about this?

My idea, to avoid that problem, was the following (although I think that it's not very good): create 221 TPicture components (invisible to the user of course) and load in each of them a picture of a flag.

I'd prefer not using the last idea I had. Do you know any improvement?

Comment: To avoid the IDE breaking the image into separate bitmaps you'd need to set the image list's width and height accordingly. But I would prefer having a collection of `TObjectList<TPngImage>` assuming PNG as a used image format.

Comment: Yeah they are PNG. I found that some minutes ago in google and I was reading something about that. Could you please give some more tips?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This sort of problem is simply not suited to the form designer. You want to store 221 images, and managing that in the IDE will be horrible. Once you've got them all in you won't be able to see them readily because they will be base 16 encoded in a .dfm file. Under revision control it will be a mess because you won't be able to change individual images in a manageable and traceable manner.

The accepted way to do this is to use resources. If it were me, I'd arrange for my images to have predicatable names. For instance, `flag1`, `flag2`, etc. I'd generate a resource script (.rc) that listed all the flags. I'd compile that resource script to a compiled resource (.res) which is linked to the executable. I'd have the resource script and the image files committed to revision control.

Then at runtime you have a single `TImage` control to display the flag. Every time you need a new image you load it with `TResourceStream`, and push it into the `TImage` control.

Comment: To add, if all these images were embedded in the form, it would take a ridiculous amount of time for the form to initialize, as streaming the DFM will have to parse and convert all of them, even though it only needs 10/221 of them.

Comment: That is actually a good idea, I'm gonna implement it immediatly; thanks for the opinion!

Answer (score 1):

Devexpress has a Componnect named cximagecolletion that you can put your images on it and save and load images from/to file

or you can save all flags in small access db and load it when you need using tadodataset

there is no doubt that if you put your images direct on your form your dfm grow very high and so you Get Into trouble

Comment: In a small Access DB ? And redistribute MS Access along with your app.?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would store each file as an image in a dedicated subdirectory, using the country as a file name. Then I would read the subdirectory file names on entry to the program (so I have a list of countries that I can randomly choose from) and use TImage.LoadFromFile to display the flag. This is far easier to extend than using a resource file (IMHO).